# Invalid cast when getting object from ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have a ListView which is being populated with `IDevice` from an ObservableCollection. `IDevice` is basically a Bluetooth device in the periphery. I.e. An object.

When a user presses a given device in the ListView, I ultimately want it to call my `Connect()` method. - but for now, it is just commented out as I'm testing.

```
listView.ItemTapped += async (s, e) => 
{
    var answer = await DisplayAlert("Tapped", "Connect to device?", "Yes", "No");
    if(answer == true)
    {
        IDevice name = (IDevice)e;
        await DisplayAlert("name of BLE", name.Name + " " + name.State.ToString(), "OK");
        //Connect((IDevice)e);
    }
};
```

The problem is, that I'm doing an invalid cast when I get inside the if statement. i.e. `(IDevice)e`.

I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e` is type [ItemTappedEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.itemtappedeventargs?view=xamarin-forms), which contains a property `Item`

```
IDevice name = (IDevice)e.Item;
```